# get selectlist value through apex code in outputtext

Tags: salesforce, cloud

```
public with sharing class soption 
{
public list<selectoption> list1 = new list<selectoption>();
public list<Patient_Registration__c > list2 = new list<Patient_Registration__c >();
public String listvalue {get;set;}
public String outputtextvalue {get; set;}
public Patient_Registration__c  value {get; set;}

public soption(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
value=(Patient_Registration__c )controller.getRecord();
}
public list<selectoption> getoptionlist()
{
 list2=[select id, Name__c from Patient_Registration__c ];
 list1.add(new selectoption('--Select options--', '--Select options--'));
 for(Patient_Registration__c pr:list2)
 {
   list1.add(new selectoption(pr.id,pr.Name__c));
 }
return list1;
}
public String getselectedtext()
{
outputtextvalue =listvalue;
return listvalue;
}
}
```

Visual page code is

```
<apex:page standardController="Patient_Registration__c" extensions="soption">
<apex:form >
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!listvalue}" onchange="{!selectedtext}">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!optionlist}">
</apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:outputText value="{!selectedtext}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Not able to get the value of listvalue in the outputtexvalue.
outputtext value is used in the outputtext and the list value used in the select list.
Please help me to get the value of select list in the outputtext.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardController="Patient_Registration__c" extensions="soption">
<apex:form id="myForm">
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!listvalue}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionlist}">
    <apex:actionSupport rerender="myForm" event="onchange"/>
</apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:outputText value="{!selectedtext}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```